# Desnormalización en la tabla Pais de la información de la Moneda en SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, modelorelacional

Tengo esta relacion y necesito desnormalizarla
[image: Tengo esta relacion y necesito desnormalizarla a la siguiente]

Siendo esta segunda imagen el resultado y al final de esta dice lo que se necesita hacer EN SQL SERVER

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son los cdatos que tiene el campo moneda en la tabla pais.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias.....

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Lee [ask] y [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](/help/on-topic)

Comment: ¿Necesitas denormalizarla y entonces, la normalizaste?

Comment: Dices desnormalizar, pero describes el proceso de normalización.